# sql loader issue with select count

Tags: sql, sql-loader

I am trying to use the sql loader to load data from the csv file. I am getting issue with count for some reason the count is always 0.

Data:

```
Market yield on U.S. Treasury securities at 1-month   constant maturity
Market yield on U.S. Treasury securities at 2-month   constant maturity
Market yield on U.S. Treasury securities at 3-month   constant maturity
...
```

control file:

```
OPTIONS()
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'first.csv'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE US_FI_LOOKUP 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
lang_code constant "en",
name terminated by '\n',
id "(select count(*)+1 from US_FI_LOOKUP)"
)
```

Comment: you are trying to do a `count(*)` on the table with `0` rows, assuming it was empty before loading data. The table would only have rows after the control file runs successfully. What is the `id` column supposed to be? is it a sequentially generated number?

Comment: it is supposed to be a count. it is not a seq number

Comment: how do you think you can get `count` without data being present in the table?

Comment: one approach would be to load the other 2 columns through the control file and then update the id column in the table with the desired count

Comment: the data will be empty at the beginning but it should increment with each record loaded? what is the best way to do it just add an ID column with count of records

Comment: One way may be to try the `ROWS=1` parameter in the options. I would not recommend this if you are indeed loading large volumes of data.

Comment: yes that worked. it is not large amount of data like 30-100 records.